# Strange Behaviour when Creating an Array of Arrays with new Array and Fill in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

When I create an array of empty arrays with the following code:

```
const arrayOfArrays = new Array(3).fill([])
```

As expected, I get `[[],[],[]`. However let's say I change the value with:

```
arrayOfArrays[0][0] = 'foo'
```

I expect to get `[['foo'],[],[]]` but I end up with `[['foo'],['foo'],['foo']]`. Why is this the case? How can I get it so that it works as expected?

Comment: Use `Array.from` instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance this is no duplicate to the question you posted, this is actually the exact opposite question...

Comment: @Gibor It's the same. OP is trying to create an array of arrays - to add the same element (an array) to another array 3 times. As described in the linked answer, `.fill` doesn't work well with non-primitives because then there are multiple copies of the *exact same object* in memory, so mutations to one object affects all objects in the array, as OP is experiencing here. The solution is to create a new object on each iteration, which can be done concisely with `Array.from`